# UISplitViewController - Detail on the Left?

Tags: ios, ios7, uisplitviewcontroller, ios8

Does anyone know how to reverse the display of the master/detail view controllers in a UISplitViewController? I basically just want to display the master list on the right side of the screen instead of the left, but want to preserve all actions the split view controller does to the master list (hides it and brings it back on screen - just want it to animate from the right instead of the left). I see that ios8 has added some much needed functionality to the UISplitViewController, but I'm not sure how to acheive this one little thing from it. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just switch the functionality around? Instead of setting the detail view from the (left master), make the right the master and set the detail view of the left pane ?

Comment: That's not exactly what I'm looking for, as it would make the left pane always visible with the right pane toggle able. I still want to make the left pane togglable with regards to its visibility. Basically, like Xcode has with the right pane, where it presents a list of options to the user and is not used to guide the contents of the detail view, but instead is used to present options related to the contents of the detail view..

Answer (score 5):

This is supported as of iOS 11 by UISplitViewController's [`primaryEdge`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisplitviewcontroller/2875524-primaryedge?changes=latest_minor) property. This code snippet makes the master pane show on the right, detail on the left:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
                 launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let splitViewController = window!.rootViewController as! UISplitViewController
    splitViewController.primaryEdge = .trailing
}
```

This answer is 3 years too late, but hopefully useful to someone with this question after iOS 11's release.

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to support earlier versions (iOS 10.x) and probably has necessity to respect UI changes according to such languages as Hebrew, Arabic, etc..

```
splitViewController.view.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

This answer is nearly 4 years too late, but I also do hope that someone finds it useful

Comment: Really thanks for your answer. By the way is there any unexpected affect from that?

Comment: @rener172846 the forceRightToLeft method for different UIViews sometimes doesn't work in some iOS 9.x versions without indicating any errors in Xcode. I've tested UISplitView today on iOS 9.3, it worked fine, so you can consider using this method at least from iOS 9.3, but you should better test lower versions of iOS 9. On the newer versions it works like a charm, our team fully relies on this method for iOS 10,11